# Rendering Html content for Header Block

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to get my header part as html and I will use this in some other site with API call. For that I am trying to render using `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header` block and the following code:

```
$this->_view->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header')
    ->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
```

But it is not working. Can someone please suggest how to correct this or some other method to implement.

Comment: what you getting by this code?

Comment: I am getting the error like `Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::html/footer.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Theme' block's name: 'html\\footer_0'`

Comment: try without template `$this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header')->toHtml();`

Comment: I am trying to do this also, but I've got an empty string as result. Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer")
    ->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/footer.phtml")
    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the post, this is to be implemented as Api. I can't use $this class in model or even in controller to get the layout

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `$block` for any reason instead of `$this->_view`?

**update**

One more thing, template path should use / instead of \

```
Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml
```

Comment: particular reason for using the $this->_view, as mentioned in the post I am going to use this as API. So I need to get the html in model. In model it is not possible to use $block->getLayout() or $this->getLayout().

Comment: Actually I was used the template as `Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml`. But in the post only by mistake I put the back slash

Comment: which error do you see? or it just doesn't print anything? any info in var/log files?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the error like Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::html/footer.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Theme' block's name: 'html\\footer_0'

Comment: Try setting just html/header.phtml, without specifying module